# How to Sort Array According to TimeWise?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to sort array according to AM and PM value of time...

I have got the response like below:

```
(
    {
        Rate = "4.44";
        Count = 3;
        Hours = "04:00 PM";
    },
    {

        Rate = "5.55";
        Count = 5;
        Hours = "07:00 AM";
    },
    {
        Rate = "3.33";
        Count = 2;
        Hours = "08:00 PM";
    }
)
```

I want to sort the hours to display it time wise according to AM and PM.

Comment: Have you tried something ??

Comment: what kind of array jsonArray or NSArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to convert the Hours strings to objects of class `NSDate`:

```
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
        df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

        NSDate *dateA = [df dateFromString:[a objectForKey:@"Hours"]];
        NSDate *dateB = [df dateFromString:[b objectForKey:@"Hours"]];

        return [dateA compare:dateB];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this one help you...

```
 NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"09:00 AM",@"07:30 AM",@"06:45 PM",@"05:00 PM",@"12:45 AM",@"12:45 PM",@"01:00 AM",@"01:15 PM", nil];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

 NSArray *sortedTimes = [times sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
 {
     NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
     NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];
     return [date1 compare:date2];
 }];
```

optimized version:

```
 NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"09:00 AM",@"07:30 AM",@"06:45 PM",@"05:00 PM",@"12:45 AM",@"12:45 PM",@"01:00 AM",@"01:15 PM", nil];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

 NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:times.count];
 for (NSString *timeString in times)
 {
     NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
     [dates addObject:date];
 }

 [dates sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

 NSMutableArray *sortedTimes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dates.count];
 for (NSDate *date in dates)
 {
     NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
     [sortedTimes addObject:timeString];
 }
```